# compare 2 time in php

Tags: php, datetime, compare

I need to compare the start and end times of events before I store them in my DB.Event date & time is greater than or equal to the current time, only then i store them in the db

I am using the following code for comparing time & date. But it not working. Is there any way I can compare these times?

```
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$dates = $_POST['date'];
$time = date("g:i:a");
$time1 = $_POST['time'];
$meridiem = $_POST['meridiem'];
$c_time = $time1.':'.$meridiem; //eg: 1:00:am
if(($dates >= $date) && (strtotime($c_time) > strtotime($time))){
//block of code
}
```

Comment: `1:00:am` is not a valid time format. try `1:00 am`.

Comment: @user2164054 what is $dates ... ? and what is the format of $_POST['time'] and $_POST['merdiem'].....?

Comment: This if will always fail if that is the complete code. Apart from what @AshwiniAgarwal suggested there is another issue that `$dates` is not defined anywhere. Hence `$dates >=$date` will always be false

Comment: the result of $time = date("g:i:a"); is in this format 1:00:am

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure that `$_POST['time'];` gives you a result similar to `m/d/Y` and  `$_POST['meridiem'];` give you a result similar to `g:i a` (1:00 am). 
the code did not work at the beginning because of the `strtotime()` function. it probably did not recognize if your string is a date or not.

```
$date = date("m/d/Y");
$time = date("g:i a");
$time1 = $_POST['time'];
$meridiem = $_POST['meridiem'];
$c_time = $time1.' '.$meridiem; //eg: 1:00 am
if(($dates >= $date) && (strtotime($c_time) > strtotime($time))){
//block of code
}
```

In addition, you did not define `$dates` in your query . you can define as follow to make your code work:

```
$dates = date('m/d/Y g:i a');
```

Comment: `$dates` also needs to be defined somewhere.